# How to insert decimal after the first character in whole number in SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm creating a report which displays the grades of student but the problem is the system only accepts whole number. And I need to display grades with decimal.

I tried using CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), @VALUE / 1000.00) but the result is not what i need.

Here's my code

```
, (CASE WHEN (SELECT TRNSFR_SRC_TYPE FROM PS_TRNS_CRSE_SCH WHERE EMPLID in (dtl.EMPLID) AND MODEL_NBR = dtl.MODEL_NBR AND ACAD_CAREER = dtl.ACAD_CAREER) = 'M' AND CRSE_ID <> '' THEN
(CASE WHEN (SELECT GRADE_POINTS FROM PS_GRADE_TBL WHERE CRSE_GRADE_INPUT = dtl.CRSE_GRADE_OFF AND GRADING_SCHEME = dtl.GRADING_SCHEME AND GRADING_BASIS = dtl.GRADING_BASIS) <> 0 THEN CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), (SELECT CAST(ROUND(GRADE_POINTS, 2) AS NUMERIC(12,2)) FROM PS_GRADE_TBL WHERE CRSE_GRADE_INPUT = dtl.CRSE_GRADE_OFF AND GRADING_SCHEME = dtl.GRADING_SCHEME AND GRADING_BASIS = dtl.GRADING_BASIS)) / 1000.00
ELSE
convert(decimal (10, 2) ,dtl.CRSE_GRADE_OFF / 1.00)
```

I expect the output should be 1.00 or 1.50 or 5.00. If the value is 500 then it should output of 5.00 another example is 150 then it should display as 1.50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all the help, I found the solution to my problem by using CAST

```
cast(cast(CRSE_GRADE_INPUT as decimal(10,2))* 0.01 as decimal(10,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing formatting options (Textbox Properties) of the specified column. It is generally related with formatting not the SQL itself.

[image]

Comment: Hi, it is already set as 2 decimal places but it remain as 500 and not 5.00

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the field, going to the Properties Pane an under Number > Format, changing the format to: 0.00. I entered a few numbers and this was working for me.

[SSRS Properties Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taj8n.png)

Comment: Hi, didn't work for me, the result is still the same. Thanks.